# Spring boot error: org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-boot

In `SpringApplication.run(DemosApplication.class, args);` I got the error:

```
org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved
```

Screenshots of it:

[image]

[image]

This is my source code in sts:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemosApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemosApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: [Why you should not post images instead of code and error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @RandomGuy: Please reconsider reverting the downvote in this case. The OP is just showing a screenshot of the error, reinforcing what exactly he is talking about. That is perfectly valid - in case the error is also written as text somewhere in the question. I just edited the question to include the error message, it may take a while to be processed. Cheers

Comment: I see a red `!` - maybe your maven-dependencies are not resolved?